# Why are some robust algorithms valid for Tucker decomposition, but not for CP decomposition?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-decomposition, tensor

I have been reading up about CP and Tucker decomposition. 
It makes sense that CP decomposition is a special case of Tucker decomposition, where the core tensor is super-diagonal. However, if this is the case, **why does a best approximation always exist for the Tucker format but not the Canonical format?**

This doesn't make sense to me intuitively. If the Tucker decomposition is a generalization of CP decomposition, then surely the robust Tucker algorithms must be applicable in both cases.

> Tucker format does not
>   suffer from the ill-posedness of approximation problems. [1]

Admittedly, I have not read [2] as it is very dense (for me at least), but I got the main points.

If you could link any resources that would be helpful in my understanding, that would be very nice too!

[1] "The Tensor-Train Format and Its Applications" - https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/fub188/3366/dissertation_pg_final.pdf?sequence=1

[2] "Tensor rank and the ill-posedness of the best low-rank approximation problem" - https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607647