# Spiked tensor decomposition vs canonical polyadic decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, signal-processing

What are the similarities and differences between [Spiked tensor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05424.pdf) decomposition and [canonical polyadic (CP) decomposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11414)?

My understanding is that CP decomposition aims to find a low-rank approximation of the full tensor. Spiked tensor decomposition aims to recover a planted low-rank structure within a full tensor.

Are there cases where they overlap? Is there a way one can understand any one of them as a specialization of the other? Also, is there any special scenario where both problems may be solved using the same approach or algorithm?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407122/why-are-some-robust-algorithms-valid-for-tucker-decomposition-but-not-for-cp-de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they are both tensor factorization algorithms, Canonical Polyadic (CP) decomposition and Spiked Tensor (ST) Decomposition serve different purposes and are applied in different situations.

ST decomposition is often used as a statistical procedure in data analysis and especially signal processing, where it is assumed that there exists a “spiked” structure (a scenario where a low-rank signal tensor, which contains the significant information, is obscured by noise). Separating this low-rank signal from the noisy observations is the main goal of this approach. It is assumed that the signal has a lower rank than the noise, which tends to increase the tensor's rank. Estimates or predetermined assumptions regarding the signal and noise levels are needed in order to accomplish this successfully. This process is meant to be applied in situations where it is expected that there would be a low-rank structure visible above the noise. The trick is to correctly extract this signal so that the underlying patterns or trends in the data can be seen.

On the other hand, for higher-order tensors, Canonical Polyadic (CP) Decomposition functions as a generalisation of matrix singular value decomposition (SVD). Its goal is to reduce the data to a sequence of vector outer products by decomposing a tensor into a sum of rank-one tensors. The goal is to reduce the tensor to a low-rank approximation in a more compact representation while retaining the basic structure. This decomposition technique is unsupervised; it does not rely on prior information about the rank or any particular internal structure of the tensor. It is used in a more general setting where identifying the major variance in the data is the main goal rather than trying to distinguish between signal and noise. A noteworthy difficulty in CP decomposition is the potential non-uniqueness, especially when dealing with tensors of rank greater than two.

While both ST decomposition and CP decomposition aim to exploit low-rank structures within tensors, and they are both extensions of matrix decomposition techniques, there are key differences in their objectives and applications. CP decomposition does not typically account for noise and aims to minimise the overall difference between the tensor and its low-rank approximation. ST decomposition, however, is explicitly tailored to separate out the signal from the noise, often employing a probabilistic approach to differentiate between the two.

There may be situations in which the methods overlap. For example, CP decomposition could efficiently carry out ST decomposition when the tensor has a prominent low-rank structure with low noise since the low-rank approximation would be sufficient to capture the signal. On the other hand, if the signal-to-noise ratio is very low in a ST decomposition, the output may resemble that of a CP decomposition since the signal is the dominant component.

In order to identify the underlying signal, it is possible to see ST decomposition as a specific type of CP decomposition when extra structure or information regarding the presence of noise is included. Conversely, CP decomposition is a more universal method that does not require any particular assumptions about the tensor components. Similar optimisation approaches that are employed in CP decomposition can be used for ST decomposition when the tensor shows a strong signal that can be distinguished from the noise.

An algorithm's suitability is determined by the rank of the underlying signal, the type and amount of noise present, and the specific structure of the tensor. Therefore, ST decomposition is a more nuanced method that concentrates on separating the signal from the noise, whereas CP decomposition offers a more general framework for tensor factorization. They may use comparable algorithms in situations when the tensor characteristics allow.